# How to specify a custom output size in cv2.pyrDown() or pyrUp() method

Tags: python, opencv

I want to explicitly specify the output size of the image when applying [cv2.pyrDown()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaf9bba239dfca11654cb7f50f889fc2ff) on images.

```
def gaussian_pyramid(image, scale=1.5, minSize=(30, 30)):
    yield image
    while True:
        w = int(image.shape[1] / scale)
        h = int(image.shape[0] / scale)
        image = cv2.pyrDown(image, dstsize=(w, h))
        if image.shape[0] < minSize[1] or image.shape[1] < minSize[0]:
            break
        yield image
```

But it is throwing an error something similar to this.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 && std::abs(dsize.width*2 - ssize.width) <= 2 && std::abs(dsize.height*2 - ssize.height) <= 2) in pyrDown_, file /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/pyramids.cpp, line 873
```

Any idea how to specify the output size of the image as a method argument.

Answer (score 1):

From OpenCV 2.4 Tutorial:

> `pyrDown( tmp, dst, Size( tmp.cols/2, tmp.rows/2 )`
>
> tmp: The current image, it is initialized with the src original image.
>
> dst: The destination image (to be shown on screen, **supposedly half the input image**)
>
> Size( tmp.cols/2, tmp.rows/2): The destination size. Since we are downsampling, **pyrDown expects half the size the input image** (in this case tmp).
>
> Notice that it is important that the input image can be divided by a factor of two (in both dimensions). Otherwise, an error will be shown.

This was taken from the C++ tutorial but it should apply just the same for Python.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I forget to give the correct answer which was given [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/183566/how-to-specify-a-custom-output-size-in-cv2pyrdown-or-cv2pyrup-method/).

pyrdown, pyrup go with a factor of 2. Thus, to work odd sizes we have to adjest the `dstsize` is with +- 1 pixel.

```
def gaussian_pyramid(image, scale=2, minSize=(60, 60)):
   yield image
   while True:
     w = int(image.shape[1] / scale)
     h = int(image.shape[0] / scale)
     image = cv2.pyrDown(image, dstsize=(w,h))
     if image.shape[0] < minSize[1] or image.shape[1] < minSize[0]:
        break
     yield image
```